# Docker System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The parameter is incorrect

Tags: docker

I am getting this error when trying to launch the Docker Desktop app. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Docker.

Answer (score 2):

I had to remove the Docker Host Filesystem Access record in Credential Manager.

Comment: I had the same problem - now solved after removing the credentials for Docker. Thanks!